# Matlab fmincon for a problem with many nonlinear constraints

Tags: solver, nonlinear-programming, matlab

Using Matlab to solve a problem which has linear objective function and many nonlinear constraints, I am trying to generate the inequality nonlinear constraints by a function and pass it to fmincon solver via *nonlcon* option. My question is if there are no equality nonlinear constraints in the model what should the constraints generator pass to fmincon? I tried the following:

```
function [c, ceq] = consgenerator(x) 

c = @(x) *[some constraints]*;  

ceq = [];    

end
```

In another attempt, I tried:

```
ceq = @(x) [];
```

I got errors in both trials and couldn’t find an example of passing many nonlinear inequality constraints into fmincon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem might be `@(x)` in the first line of the function. Adding this creates an anonymous function, while MATLAB simply expects a numerical vector as output. Removing `@(x)` should resolve the issue. Using `ceq = []` should not give any problems.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I will definitely give a try...

Answer (score 8):

Following [Kevin Dalmeijer](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/145/kevin-dalmeijer)'s [answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1460/39) (*Accepted*), I found the following approach to solve the problem that I had. (*composing this answer for future similar questions*):

The general form of Fmincon function (minimizing constrained nonlinear multivariable function) in Matlab optimization toolbox is as follow:

```
Option 1: fmincon(ObjFun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@nonlcon,options); or 
Option 2: fmincon(ObjFun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options);
```

in which **nonlcon** (used to add the nonlinear constraints to the model) can be a function name or a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html?s_tid=doc_ta) (by putting @ before function's name). Two mentioned expressions have a very slight difference in their implementation.

- For the first case, as Kevin mentioned you can define a function with the same name and generate all the nonlinear constraints (including Equality and Inequality) and return `[c,ceq]` to Fmincon as the output of the defined **nonlcon** function. In this option, `c` and `ceq` can be two vectors of residual.
- In the second option, function handle should be either defined outside of definition of Fmincon or defined inside the **nonlcon** function.

Explanation of all the other variables in fmincon can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html?searchHighlight=fmincon&s_tid=doc_srchtitle).

I tried the combination of two approaches which caused the error in my code.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify many nonlinear constraints and objectives without having to define functions with the problem-based modeling approach starting with MATLAB R2019a. "Many" are those that are polynomial or rational expressions. For example:

```
p = optimproblem;
x = optimvar("x","LowerBound",0);
y = optimvar("y","LowerBound",0);
p.Objective = x + y;
p.ObjectiveSense = "min";
p.Constraints.c1 = x^2 - y^2 >= 10;
initPt.x = 4;
initPt.y = 4;
sol = solve(p,initPt)
```

For other expressions, you will still need to write functions. Details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/problem-based-approach.html).